# Change of Nationality

Tags: united-kingdom, nationality

I have a UK spouse visa (biometric) on a pakistani passport, but recently about 3 weeks ago I received Bahraini nationality where I was born and bought up.

Would this affect me if I apply for ILR and do I need to inform home office regarding the change in passport, as on my biometric it says Nationalty pakistani but I have a Bahraini passport now.
what can be done for me to change my biometric to Bahraini?

Comment: For which country is your visa?

Comment: UK spouse visa on pakistani passport

Comment: Are you still a Pakistani citizen + passport holder, or did you give that up when you took the Bahraini citizenship?

Comment: yes i have surrenderd my pakistani passport when i took my bahraini passport

Comment: still no reply from no one any

Answer (score 3):

You **must** apply for a new biometric residence permit within 3 months if your nationality changes.

The [British Residency Permit Guidance Notes](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/261497/brp-information-leaflet.pdf) have more information on this (bolds are my amendments):

> You must tell us as soon as you can if:
>
> - you change your name (for example, because of marriage or by deed poll);
> - you change your gender, legally or permanently;
> - **you change your nationality**; or
> - your facial appearance changes significantly.
>
> If you change any personal details listed above or any details shown on your 
>   biometric residence permit, you must apply for a new permit within three 
>   months using application form BRP (RC). If you do not do this, **you may have to
>   pay a financial penalty of up to £1,000 or we may shorten your permission to
>   stay.**